# How to Align/Straighten/make Coplanar Non-planar edge between adjacent edges?

Tags: geometry

I've just started learning Blender and I have a situation where I have 2 non-vertical faces (not parallel to any axis) with a common edge which is currently not coplanar to other 2 vertical edges.

I am trying to move this edge along the Y-axis until both faces become coplanar but I don't know how to go about it. It's probably really simple but I've been using MicroStation for 20 years and how I would do it in that is likely different to how it should be done in Blender.

[image]

Comment: so you want all the faces on the end to be flat and straight?

Comment: Yes, the 2 select faces should in a line with each other

Comment: in this simple case the simplest thing imho is delete the shared edge and rebuild faces (I know, far from optimal and cool).

Comment: If I do that then I also need to delete the top faces, recreate the top and the vertical face. I found I couldnt then add end edge loop on the new face for some reason so had to use the knife tool to and the edges in again. Seems a lot of work instead of a simple edge transformation.

Comment: what about deleting the Edge-Loop in the mid and create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Apart rebuilding faces, as I said in comments above, here you find a possible way or sort of inspiration for a more "elegant" method, involving the "magic" Knife tool:

here is a similar setup to your situation:

[image]

we're going to use the knife tool to add a "guide" vertex to which we'll snap later, making the two selected faces planar again.

[image]

after activating the knife tool, it will show a green square when it "snaps" to a starting vertex: click here.

[image]

then, drag until it snaps the end vertex: click here too, then "confirm" pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

note: the knife tool will "cut through" your mesh and create an intermediate vertex just where you need it (you see a preview before "confirming")

[image]

now you simply need to activate snap on vertixes, and drag your shared edge (locking Z in this case) until it snaps perfectly to the vertex just created by the knife tool

[image]

[image]

and now you just need to use "remove doubles" to remove the "guide vertex" we added before, and you're done!

[image]

[image]

Hth.

Comment: Just getting back to this...  Thanks for the example. I can see it works though I'm keen to find out if using transform orientations can give me the same result. Another example: http://imgur.com/DoBKw9R . I have created an edge between 2 vertices and I want the edge/vertices where the slope meets the lower horizontal faces to move up in the Z direction to the intersection with the edge.

Comment: btw, I know it's not _that_ elegant but at least this allows you precise positioning without rebuilding all. Maybe you could describe what (an how) you would like it work (as in microstation, eg) submitting a feature request...

Comment: I've seen examples which advise to make a custom transform orientation using the edge, set 'Cursor to Selection', Set Pivot to 3D cursor, snapping to edge, border select the vertices to move and double tap Z to constrain the the transform. The problem with this is that it doesn't move the vertices along the Global Z axis and is not the result I am looking for.

Comment: In MicroStation I dont work with quads or meshes so its kinda different. One thing I may to is draw a line from the source vertices, lock its direction to only the Z axis and have it terminate at the intersection with the sloping edge. That way I have a vertex to snap to when moving the edges or vertices. SketchUp has the tape-measure tool which lets the user draw construction guides in the same manner, 1 for the slope, another for the Z axis from the line of source vertices. I would like to think Blender has its own workflow for this but my lack of experience leaves me unsure.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game, but the simplest way I know to do this generically is to double tap <kbd>G</kbd>, slide the edge to one slide, and <kbd>LeftClick</kbd> to apply.  Then repeat the process and drag it to where you want it.

[image]